# C# Generics, Constrain to Specific Structs

Tags: c#, generics, struct

Is it possible to constrain a genericised method to accept only specific types of struct?

This is OK I believe:

```
string Add<T>(object value, T expiration) where T : struct;
```

but this isn't it appears:

```
string Add<T>(object value, T expiration) where T : Struct1, Struct2;
```

Note: the structs I wish to constrain it to are DateTime or TimeSpan and hence I have no control over them.

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, as a struct is sealed (you can't create a subclass of a ValueType).

Instead, consider having your structs implement an interface, then use that as a constraint, like so:

`string Add<T>(object value, T expiration) where T : struct, IMyInterface`

Comment: I agree that this should be achieved with interfaces. This is one of the purposes of an interface!

Comment: Thanks for your answer - please can you explain the significance of not being able to subclass the type? Constraining the parameter to structs (value types) appears possible and contradictory to your statement. The structs I wish to constrain it to are DateTime or TimeSpan, so wrapping these in an interface would seem to be the only solution (or leave un genericised).

Comment: You can't enforce a new interface on a struct you don't control (`DateTime`, `TimeSpan` etc), so no: you can't do this.

Comment: He means you can't derive from a value type (int, struct, double). You can constrain it to all structs, but you can't constrain it to particular structs.

Comment: If you need to use this for classes or struct that you do not control you should make people aware of that.  Using the name "MyStruct" in your question is misleading.

Comment: You'd need to wrap (decorate) the DateTime or TimeSpan in a custom struct or class if you wanted to do this. In practice it sounds like having two overloads of Add() would be better here: Add(object value, TimeSpan expiration) and Add(object value, DateTime expiration). Your code will be different in both cases anyway...

Comment: I apologise for the misleading question.

Comment: @MarcGravell on "you can't enforce a new interface" Ha, true, and true in so many mainstream languages! OTOH In Haskell you totally can, for example... Paradigms, paradigms

Comment: Although this is my favorite answer, but remember that there is boxing/unboxing complication for a struct implementing an interface, which may result in poorer performance in the intense circumstances.

Answer (score 7):

The purpose of generics is to make methods and types that are *generic*, hence the name. If you only have two possible type arguments, then just write two methods.

Remember also, C# generics are not C++ templates. When you call a method on a type parameter, say, that method call will be the *exact same method call* for *every* construction of the type parameter. It's *generic*. It's not a template where the compiler compiles the code two, three, a thousand times, one for each type argument, and works out afresh for each one what the method call is.

So even if you *could* restrict your type argument to two types, what good would that do you? All you could call on them was the methods they had in common via their base class, Object.  In which case, you've got a generic method that works on all objects, so why restrict it to two types?

Comment: Could using `void Foo<T>(T x) where T : I` instead of `void Foo(I x)`help avoid boxing of `x` when `T` is a by-value type? [Here is a related question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31457682/335858).

Answer (score 5):

I expect an overload is your best option here:

```
string Add(object value, MyStruct1 expiration) {...}
string Add(object value, MyStruct2 expiration) {...}
```

This is even more appropriate since you can't subclass a struct, thus the *only* viable `T` in your example **would be** `MyStruct1` and `MyStruct2` - may as well have specific methods, then.

Re restricting generics to multiple cited types; not really - and even if there were, the name "Add" suggests you'd want to use operator support, which *also* isn't in C# (3.0).

However, in C# 4.0, `dynamic` might be an option here - this acts as an optimised form of duck-typing; you wouldn't get compiler support (validation etc), but it should work. You would cast to `dynamic` *inside* the method:

```
string Add<T>(object value, T expiration) where T : struct {
    dynamic valueDyn = value;
    valueDyn += expiration; // or similar
    // more code
}
```

Another option (in .NET 3.5) is to use the [`Operator` support](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/miscutil/usage/genericoperators.html) in [MiscUtil](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/miscutil/), using `Operator.Add` or `Operator.AddAlternative`.

Answer (score -3):

I think both are not OK, a struct is not a valid constraint. A type used as a constraint must be interface, non sealed or a type parameter

Comment: Indeed, there are other constraints beyond types: "new()" "struct" or "class".