# Do C# generics prevent autoboxing of structs in this case?

Tags: c#, generics, interface, autoboxing

Usually, treating a struct `S` as an interface `I` will trigger autoboxing of the struct, which can have impacts on performance if done often. However, if I write a generic method taking a type parameter `T : I` and call it with an `S`, then will the compiler omit the boxing, since it knows the type `S` and does not have to use the interface?

This code shows my point:

```
interface I{
    void foo();
}

struct S : I {
    public void foo() { /* do something */ }
}

class Y {

    void doFoo(I i){
        i.foo();
    }
    void doFooGeneric<T>(T t) where T : I {
        t.foo(); // <--- Will an S be boxed here??
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args){
        S x;
        doFoo(x); // x is boxed
        doFooGeneric(x); // x is not boxed, at least not here, right?
    }

}
```

The `doFoo` method calls `foo()` on an object of type `I`, so once we call it with an `S`, that `S` will get boxed. The `doFooGeneric` method does the same thing. However, once we call it with an `S`, no autoboxing might be required, since the runtime knows how to call `foo()` on an `S`. But will this be done? Or will the runtime blindly box `S` to an `I` to call the interface method?

Comment: Try adding the `struct` constraint - ie `void doFooGeneric<T>(T t) where T : struct, I {`

Comment: FWIW, using the `IsBoxed` function from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5807132/791010) says that it's not boxed.  I don't know the details of why though.

Comment: Related if not duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3032750/structs-interfaces-and-boxing and specially [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3033357/961113) by Marc Gravell

Comment: @JamesThorpe As far as I can see you cannot use that method to see if `t` is boxed in the `t.foo()` call.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen You wouldn't... you'd do it inside `doFooGeneric`?  [Like this](http://imgur.com/SwDaYeG)?

Comment: @JamesThorpe That just shows that `t` is not boxed inside the method `doFooGeneric`. It does not show what happens when `t.foo()` executes. Suppose we wrote `t.ToString()` instead of `t.foo()`. That **would** box because our `S` does not `override` `ToString`. Or if we had `t.GetType()`, that would always box (`GetType()` is non-virtual so never overridden).

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Hmm... I thought we were only finding out whether or not `t` was boxed in `doFooGeneric`...  I think I need to go read some more...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
void doFooGeneric<T>(T t) where T : I {
    t.foo(); // <--- Will an S be boxed here??
}
```

Boxing will be avoided there!

The struct type `S` is sealed. For value type versions of the type parameter `T` to your method `doFooGeneric` above, the C# compiler gives code that calls the relevant struct member directly, without boxing.

Which is cool.

See Sameer's answer for some technical details.

---

OK, so I came up with an example of this. I will be interested in better examples if anyone has some:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace AvoidBoxing
{
  static class Program
  {
    static void Main()
    {
      var myStruct = new List<int> { 10, 20, 30, }.GetEnumerator();
      myStruct.MoveNext(); // moves to '10' in list

      //
      // UNCOMMENT ONLY *ONE* OF THESE CALLS:
      //

      //UseMyStruct(ref myStruct);
      //UseMyStructAndBox(ref myStruct);

      Console.WriteLine("After call, current is now: " + myStruct.Current); // 10 or 20?
    }

    static void UseMyStruct<T>(ref T myStruct) where T : IEnumerator<int>
    {
      myStruct.MoveNext();
    }

    static void UseMyStructAndBox<T>(ref T myStruct)
    {
      ((IEnumerator<int>)myStruct).MoveNext();
    }
  }
}
```

Here the type of `myStruct` is a mutable value-type which holds a reference back to the `List<>`, and also holds "counter" that remembers what index in the `List<>` we have reached until now.

I had to use `ref`, otherwise the value-type would be copied by value when passed into either of the methods!

When I uncomment the call to `UseMyStruct` (only), this method moves the "counter" inside our value type one position ahead. If it did that in a boxed copy of the value type, we would not see it in the original instance of the struct.

To see what the difference is with boxing, try the call `UseMyStructAndBox` instead (comment `UseMyStruct` again). It creates a box at the cast, and the `MoveNext` happens on a copy. So the output is different!

---

To those who are unhappy with (or confused by) the `ref`, just write out `Current` from within the method instead. Then we can get rid of `ref`. Example:

```
static void F<T>(T t) where T : IEnumerator<int>
{
  t.MoveNext(); // OK, not boxed
  Console.WriteLine(t.Current);
}

static void G<T>(T t) where T : IEnumerator<int>
{
  ((IEnumerator<int>)t).MoveNext(); // We said "Box!", it will box; 'Move' happens to a copy
  Console.WriteLine(t.Current);
}
```

Comment: If so, then yes, that would be very cool. But are you sure? Habib's answer states exactly the opposite.

Comment: @gexicide, no, my answer was wrong with respect to the the `where T: I` otherwise it was correct.

Comment: This optimization is extremely important for example for Array.Sort<int>. This should work.

Answer (score 3):

Boxing will be avoided as [Constrained Opcodes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.constrained.aspx) come to play in the second case.